# iOS Custom Sound Notifications Location

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications

I have some issue on where to put the sounds files for my iOS app. On android I had to put them on `platform/android/res/raw` folder and it worked. On iOS, I have my `project.xcodeproj` opened on Xcode, but when I drag my .mp3 file into the Xcode project, clean, build and run the project on my iPad, I can't make the custom sound work, I have the default sound.

My PushInit:

```
var push = PushNotification.init({
            "android": {
                "senderID": "xxxxx",
                "alert": "true",
                "badge": "true",
                "sound": "true"
            },
            "ios": {
                "gcmSandbox": "true",
                "senderID": "xxxxx",
                "alert": "true",
                "badge": "true",
                "sound": "true"
            },
```

Here is my working payload:

```
{
"registration_ids":["xxxxx"],
"notification":
   {
    "title":"Message",
    "body":"Nouvelle intervention",
    "vibrate":1,
    "sound":"sirene"
   },
"data":   
   {
    "uid":"5811e9c946755",
    "quittance":0
   },
"priority":"high",
"content_available":true
}
```

The sound "sirene" is a .caf file.

[image: screen shot 2016-10-27 at 13 56 57]

Where do I have to put the sound files? I just dragged them to the project, and added to the target.

If I click on my sound, the path is:

[image: screen shot 2016-10-27 at 14 00 36]

It put it here automatically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should import them into the *Resources* folder in the project by dragging it there in xcode. If you are on iOS 10 there is a bug the may require you to restart your phone before the custom sound will play.

Comment: It's still not working. I put them in ressources folder, added to target, and clean, build and run on my iPad. Should I delete the app and install it again ?

Comment: no that should no be needed. I believe that iOS as oposed to Android needs the file extension when custom sounds are defined. Try adding it...

Comment: You were right, thanks a lot. It's not weel written in their documentation. Thanks again !

Comment: No problem. Happy to help you out.